# Fully automated Facebook posting

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been checking out Facebook API for a few days and tried to find options for posting messages on a users behalf on his personal wall (not on a page).
Graph API provides the option to post on a user's behalf using an access token, but this access token is valid for 60 months and needs to be refreshed.

My goal is to integrate my system with Facebook and to allow scheduling a Facebook message that will be released in the far future (couple of years).
I thought that i have reached a dead end with the API, until i saw a service called [Postify](https://app.postfity.com) that claims to be able to schedule a future message. I was able to place a scheduled message for 2017 without any warning about a need to refresh the access token.

Is there a way to do this without using a robot that simulates the whole authentication process? Facebook have blocked this API as far as i know, but it looks like it is possible in some way.

Comment: I haven't developed it yet, i am researching the API in order to design it first. The question is about the API and not about my code.

Comment: Integrate ur system, what of ur system?

Comment: a system where users sign in and are able to authenticate using Facebook and write a post to our system that will be published in the future when my system finds it the right time to post.